# How to execute Solandra

Tags: java, database, solr, cassandra, solandra

I am going to use Solandra.But when I run solandra.bat file i gives me error like

> Starting Cassandra
>
> Server Error: Could not find or load main class
> solandra.SolandraServer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a classpath issue.

Have you set:

```
CASSANDRA_HOME
CASSANDRA_MAIN
```

?

This is how the classpath is setup. Check to see if this solandra.SolandraServer is in CASSANDRA_HOME\build\classes

```
set CASSANDRA_CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\build\classes\main";"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\build\classes\thrift"
```

This is how Java is executed

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% %CASSANDRA_PARAMS% -cp %CASSANDRA_CLASSPATH% "%CASSANDRA_MAIN%"
```

Comment: Here classpath and Cassandra home path are:-
ClassPath:-  "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\;C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\lib;C:\Program Files\DataStax Comm
unity\apache-cassandra\bin;C:\Solandra\Solandra-solandra\solandra-app\lib\conf"
Cassandra Home:-  C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\;C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\lib;C:\Program Files\DataStax
Community\apache-cassandra\bin;C:\Solandra\Solandra-solandra\solandra-app\lib

Comment: Cassandra Main are as follows

Comment: Cassandra Main:-  solandra.SolandraServer

Comment: and you checked for solandra\SolandraServer.class in the classpath?

Comment: Yes i have checked it.

Comment: SolandraServer class is present in Solandra package and solandra package is available in solandra.jar and i have a Solandra.jar in solandra's and cassandra's  lib directory and that path is already added in classpath.